# Add pseudo column to select with join query indicating the table name where the join came from

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with MyBatis and PostgreSQL where I need to use a mybatis discriminator. I have 10 tables which I join on a `testcase` table. I want to add a pseudo column that has a distinct value for each join so that I know from which table each join came from. I can then use this in the MyBatis discriminator.

I tried this, which obviously doesn't work because this adds 2 columns where each row has either `pseudo_name_1` or `pseudo_name_2`.

```
SELECT tc.testcaseid,
               tc.testname,

               a.accessoryfilterid,
               a.testcaseid,
               a.accessoryid,
               a.exclude
               'pseudo_name_1' AS pseudo_column,


               c.capabilityfilterid,
               c.exclude,
               c.testcaseid,
               c.capabilityid,
               'pseudo_name_2' AS psudo_column,

FROM testcase AS tc
    FULL JOIN accessoryfilter a on tc.testcaseid = a.testcaseid
    FULL JOIN capabilityfilter c on tc.testcaseid = a.testcaseid
```

I basically want 1 pseudo column where the rows with values for `accessoryfilter` have the value `pseudo_name_1` and values for `capabilityfilter` have the value `pseudo_name_2`.

Is this possible in postgres, and if so, how?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `CASE WHEN a.accessoryfilterid is null THEN 'pseudo_name_1' else 'pseudo_name_2' END;` could help? (You'd probably at least still need to refine the ELSE clause).

Comment: LEFT JOIN+COALESCE()

Comment: @wildplasser could you please elaborate? 
@HeikoJakubzik would that not just modify `a.acessoryfilterid`? I need a "shared" column across all joins for mybatis (my sql mapper) to switch over

Comment: The `CASE WHEN ...` clause is a separate column; append `as pseudo_column` after `END` in order to give it a name. So, no, it does not modify acessoryfilterid. But I can't say that I understand the requirements for a shared column in mybatis, or what the two cases are that you're looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
SELECT tc.testcaseid, tc.testname,
       a.accessoryfilterid, a.testcaseid, a.accessoryid, a.exclude,
       'pseudo_name_1' AS pseudo_column,
FROM testcase tc JOIN
     accessoryfilter a 
     ON tc.testcaseid = a.testcaseid
UNION ALL
SELECT tc.testcaseid, tc.testname,
       c.capabilityfilterid, c.exclude, c.testcaseid, c.capabilityid,
       'pseudo_name_2' AS psudo_column
FROM testcase tc JOIN 
     capabilityfilter c 
     ON tc.testcaseid = c.testcaseid;
```

Note that this also fixes the second `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

---

```
SELECT tc.testcaseid
       , tc.testname,

       , COALESCE(a.testcaseid, c.testcaseid)                   AS testcaseid   -- REDUNDANT
       , COALESCE(a.accessoryfilterid, c.capabilityfilterid)    AS filterid
       , COALESCE(a.accessoryid, c.capabilityid)                AS some_id
       , COALESCE(a.exclude, c.exclude)                         AS exclude
       , CASE         
        WHEN a.testcaseid IS NOT NULL THEN 'pseudo_name_1'
        WHEN c.testcaseid IS NOT NULL THEN 'pseudo_name_2' 
                END                                             AS pseudo_column

FROM testcase AS tc
LEFT JOIN accessoryfilter a on tc.testcaseid = a.testcaseid
LEFT JOIN capabilityfilter c on tc.testcaseid = c.testcaseid
        ;
```